# Realm list data in Swift is saving but not loading properly. New to this and not sure what the problem is. Code below

Tags: swift, realm, coreml

Below is my main view controller. The user selects images of clothing which are then categorized using CoreML and given a filename. Then, data is saved to Realm. When I call the function loadClothing(), the array is empty even though items were added during func detect. Any help is much appreciated!

```
import UIKit
import PhotosUI
import RealmSwift
import CoreML
import Vision

class ViewController: UIViewController, PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var shoesImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var shirtImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pantsImageView: UIImageView!
var documentsUrl: URL {
    return FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
}
let realm = try! Realm()

var clothing: Results<Clothing>?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadClothing()
    let clothingArray = Clothing()
    print(clothingArray)
    
}

@IBAction func addClothesButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
   pickPhotos()
            
}

@IBAction func randomizeButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    loadClothing()
    let clothingArray = Clothing()
    print(clothingArray)
   
    shirtImageView.image = load(fileName: clothingArray.shirtImages.randomElement()!)
    pantsImageView.image = load(fileName: clothingArray.pantsImages.randomElement()!)
    shoesImageView.image = load(fileName: clothingArray.shoesImages.randomElement()!)
  
}
```

//MARK: - PHPickerViewController

```
@objc func pickPhotos() {
        var config = PHPickerConfiguration()
        config.selectionLimit = 25
        config.filter = PHPickerFilter.images
        
        let pickerViewController = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
        pickerViewController.delegate = self
        self.present(pickerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

// MARK: - PHPickerViewControllerDelegate

```
func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    for result in results {
           result.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {(object, error) in
              

               
               if let image = object as? UIImage {
                   
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    guard let fileName = result.itemProvider.suggestedName else {
                        fatalError("Could not retrieve file name.")
                    }
                    print(fileName)
                    guard let ciImage = CIImage(image: image) else {
                        fatalError("Could not convert to CI Image.")
                    }
                    self.detect(image: ciImage, fileName: fileName)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

// MARK: - Core ML

```
func detect(image: CIImage, fileName: String) {
    guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: ClothingClassifier(configuration: MLModelConfiguration()).model) else {
        fatalError("Loading CoreML Model failed.")
    }
    let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { (request, error) in
        guard let results = request.results as? [VNClassificationObservation] else {
            fatalError("Model failed to process image.")
        }
    let newClothing = Clothing()
       
        if let firstResult = results.first {
            
            let uiImage = UIImage(ciImage: image)
            
            if firstResult.identifier.contains("shirts") {
               
                newClothing.shirtImages.append(fileName)
               
                
            } else if firstResult.identifier.contains("pants"){
                
                newClothing.pantsImages.append(fileName)

  
            } else if firstResult.identifier.contains("shoes") {
                
                newClothing.shoesImages.append(fileName)

            }
            
            self.save(clothing: newClothing)
            print(newClothing)
        }
    }
    
    let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: image)
    do {
    try handler.perform([request])
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

// MARK: - Data Manipulation Methods

```
func save(clothing: Clothing) {
        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(clothing)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error saving uploaded clothing. \(error)")
        }
    }
    
func loadClothing() {
        clothing = realm.objects(Clothing.self)
        print("loaded")
}

private func load(fileName: String) -> UIImage? {
    
    let fileURL = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    do {
        let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
        return UIImage(data: imageData)
    } catch {
        print("Error loading image : \(error)")
    }
    return nil
}
```

}

Clothing Class

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Clothing: Object {

let shirtImages = List<String>()
let pantsImages = List<String>()
let shoesImages = List<String>()

}
```

Comment: When posting questions you need to do some troubleshooting to help guide us in what the issue is. A good start is to add a breakpoint and step through the code line by line inspecting vars and code flow along the way. When something isn't as expected, indicate that in your QUESTION so we know where to look. Also, var names are something they aren't and there's code that simply won't do anything. For example, `let clothingArray = Clothing()` is not a clothing array at all - it's a single Realm object. And then this `print(clothingArray)` will just print the empty object you just instantiated.

Comment: There's also a few sections of code that doesn't really have much, if any error checking so that section of code could silently fail and you'd never know. Also, please check your Realm file and see if it's actually populated with data - MongoDB Realm Studio can be a real help with troubleshooting. I also noticed you've got one Realm object that stores Lists of Strings - you may want to re-thjnk that and have Shirt objects, Pants objects etc to which you can then store other information about the shirt; color, size, material etc.